# Is there a way to allow user login through respective url (host)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a situation here. The rails app uses two different url: http://test.com.au and http://test.co.uk. Each user is logged in through respective url. However the controller and form for login is the same.

What's the best way to force user login through respective url? Say if User A is from Australia then when he login through http://test.co.uk, then redirect him through http://test.com.au.

Tried to change redirect path for user after login to

```
request.protocol + respective_host + member_dashboard
```

However, when Australian user logins through UK site, they are prompt to login through UK site again. Is there a way we could allow Australian user to login through uk site, and then land him to *http://test.com.au/dashboard*, without prompting him to login again through au site?

Also, devise is used for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution `request.protocol + respective_host + member_dashboard` should address this problem provided session is set for both of the domains.

Following should do the trick i.e setting session for both domains.

You have to change you session store config in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` to following

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2`

You can check more options here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Does this work if the domain is .com.au and .com.uk?